# Update hierarchy level using SQL recursion

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql

I've recently begun working on SQL recursion and have a requirement that I'm unable to meet.

[image]

Now I need to update the child level in accordance with the parent level, for instance, Asset AS-00000016 is a parent and has hierarchy_level as 50, therefore all of its children and grandchildren should have the right hierarchical level.

I result I need is this
[image]

I've created this query which only half completes the task.

```
WITH RECURSIVE asset_hierarchy AS (       
  SELECT asset_id, parent_id, hierarchy_level   
  FROM asset         
  WHERE asset_id = 'AS-00000016'   
  UNION         
  SELECT E.asset_id, E.parent_id, ah.hierarchy_level + 1 
  FROM asset_hierarchy ah     
  JOIN asset E ON ah.asset_id = E.parent_id
)  
  UPDATE asset a SET hierarchy_level = ah.hierarchy_level  
  FROM asset_hierarchy ah    
  WHERE ah.parent_id = a.asset_id;
```

The result I'm getting is this
[image]

Could someone kindly advise me on how to fix this problem?

Comment: are you checking null condition in your sql, the first record 16 the parent id is null right

Comment: Because it is the root parent, I want to update the hierarchy listed below.

Comment: in the update `where` clause, don't get the parent hierarchy level but the current item level (`WHERE ah.asset_id = a.asset_id;`)